# How to auto-detect High [Data out] from 1 IP (Windows azure website)

Tags: security, azure, ip, traffic

I have an enemy, and he generating high data out on my website (downloading 1 file(500kb) a lot of times(many thousands)).
I know his IP.
But i cant block him, becouse i use azure website.
To be able to block IP, i need to transfer my azure website to => cloud service and enable IP security. I know about it.
But enemy has dynamic IP, he can start attack when i sleep, so i'll lose money, becouse i cant block it manually, when i sleep.

Question: How i can block IP, which generates more then 100mb/hr data out? **AUTOMATICALLY!**
I can use Azure Website or Azure Cloud Service.
Is any azure tool for it ?

Comment: any help?...any one knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried this, but here is an IIS extension that can automatically block IPs based on number requests over time.  It would block many requests for a small file.
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions

With extension installers or anything else that needs a proper 'installation' via MSI and registry keys, access into Program Files, etc., you'll need to make a startup task to your azure project config to run the installer.

I just found a guide on how to config the startup task for this exact extension:
http://blog.ehuna.org/2012/04/how_to_stop_a_denial_of_servic.html

Search for this text on the page...
How to stop a 'Denial Of Service' (DoS) attack on your ASP.NET web site, 
aka “Using the 'Dynamic IP Restrictions' IIS Extension on Windows Azure")